# Custom subdomains with htaccess

Tags: 7, subsites

I have page structures like:

- example.com/aaa
- example.com/aaa/a1
- example.com/aaa/a2
- example.com/bbb
- example.com/bbb/b1
- example.com/bbb/b2
- example/com/ccc
- ........

What I need is instead **example.com/xxx/x1**, I want users to see **xxx.example.com/x1**

How can I achieve this with a rewrite rule? Or any other suggestions?

Subdomains module does not work for me because it doesnt allow custom subdomains.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a multisite structure.

1. Under sites folder I created a folder for each subdomain like: "aaa", "bbb",...
2. I created a settings.php inside each folder (starting with php tags, do not close it though):

> ```
> include_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/default/settings.php");
> $conf['site_frontpage'] = "aaa";
> ```

(It inherits the general settings.php file since I dont need very different settings per domain)

3. Created a sites.php file inside sites folder (again starting with php tags):

> $sites['aaa.example.com'] = 'aaa';
>
> $sites['bbb.example.com'] = 'bbb';
>
> .......

Answer (score -1):

**xxx.example.com** IS a subdomain. It could be set as example.com/xxx/, or xxx.example.com, doesn't really matter. The point is, you are trying to achieve a subdomain structure. And you should be able to set subdomains.